# In Progress Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger is there a way to adjust Content-Length automatically in AutoResponder?

Tags: telerik, fiddler, content-length

I am using fiddler autoresponder to return a different JS file than the one loaded from my server originally. The adjusted file uses:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: application/javascript
...other headers
Content-Length: 37010

...the javascript code
```

At the top of the file, this Content-Length header is not automatically adjusted to the edited file though. So I have to try and load my changes, my app will crash because the Content-Length is wrong, but then I check fiddlers 'transformer' tab to see how many bytes my request body actually is, update that in my modified file, refresh again and then it works.

I have tried to change the encoding to chunked, so that I could leave out the Content-Length header, but I don't think my app knows how to decode chunked for some reason.

So my question is, is there any way to automatically update the Content-Length in the auto-responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use FiddlerScript in Fiddler classic to build your auto responder. That way the content-length is set automatically:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
     // ... some other FiddlerScript code

     // host is e.g. "localhost:3000"
     if (oSession.HostnameIs("<host>") && oSession.uriContains("<file name>.js")) {
        oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "lime"; // Makes it more visible
        if (!oSession.LoadResponseFromFile("<file path>.js")) {
            throw new ApplicationException("LoadResponseFromFile Failed!! ");
        }
        // Just loads forever if Content-Length is not added
        oSession.oResponse["Content-Length"] = oSession.responseBodyBytes.GetLength(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you so much for answering ! It kind of works, I put it inside of the OnBeforeRequest function together with the things that was there before. It does load the file correctly and set Content-Length like you said it would, But it never finishes the load of it, if i visit the file directly in the browser it shows 100% the correct file, but it just keeps spinning. Am i suppose to call something else on the oSession to make it finish the request?

Comment: @DenLilleMand I updated the answer, I am not sure why the code had worked for me, the updated part now uses `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` which seems reasonable if you want to send a response in OnBeforeRequest.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you so much for the help, I took the liberty to update the code that eventually worked for me. Feel free to edit it again if you want, it's just a suggestion.